# ASP.net: FTP issue, trying to move ASPX files from one FTP to another

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, ftpwebrequest

Here's the code:

```
response.Close()
ftpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(ftp_location & dr("FILE_LOCATION").ToString.Replace("~", ""))
ftpWebRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(ftp_user, ftp_pw)
ftpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
ftpWebRequest.UseBinary = True


                            ftpSourceRequest = WebRequest.Create(ftp_source & dr("FILE_LOCATION").ToString.Replace("~", ""))
                            ftpSourceRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(ftp_user, ftp_pw)
                            ftpSourceRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
                            ftpSourceRequest.UseBinary = True
                            Try
                                ftpSourceResponse = ftpSourceRequest.GetResponse()
                                Dim t As System.Net.FtpStatusCode = ftpSourceResponse.StatusCode

                                Dim responseStream As IO.Stream = ftpSourceResponse.GetResponseStream
                                ftpStreamWriter = New StreamWriter(ftpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
                                ftpStreamWriter.Write(New StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd)
                                dr("STATUS") = "OK"
                                dr.AcceptChanges()
                                ftpStreamWriter.Close()
                                response.Close()
                                ftpSourceResponse.Close()
                            Catch ex4 As Exception
                                response.Close()
                                ftpSourceResponse.Close()
                            End Try
```

The problem is that when I actually download the file from my source, then upload it to my destination. The only thing in the file is a piece of text that says "System.IO.Streamreader" What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see anything that stands out as wrong.

The "System.IO.Streamreader" you are getting would be the expected result if this line:

```
ftpStreamWriter.Write(New StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd)
```

was actually like this:

```
ftpStreamWriter.Write(New StreamReader(responseStream))
```

Can you double check that .ReadToEnd was in there in the version you are testing and that if compiled ok?

Assuming that isn't the issue, what happens if you do:

```
dim sToWrite as String = New StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd
debug.write(sToWrite)
ftpStreamWriter.Write(sToWrite)
```

Checking that string will at least tell you if you are reading the data correctly.

You don't include a lot of the type definitions so I had to guess on the types, but you might want to try turning on option strict to see if it catches type issues you didn't notice.

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what it was. Somehow, the ReadToEnd was overwritten. Investigating source control to find the culprit.